# Add cells in a table JS & HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the sum of the cells in the table by both columns and rows, but I am not able to do it.

I also attach the html code that I have made:

```
                 <table>
                    <caption>Cells</caption>
                    <tr>
                        <th>column 1</th>
                        <th>column 2</th>
                        <th>column 3</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>0</a></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5 </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The result I am looking for is:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Row Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 9 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 5 | 15 |
| 7 | 7 | 18 |  |

On the last cell it could be 0 or empty

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would recommend checking out and following [mcve]

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The [`HTMLTableElement` has a `rows` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) that gives you each of the rows (including header rows). Each of those [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) objects has a `cells` property for each cell in the row. From that documentation, you should be able to figure it out. If not, do some searching; there are many questions about summing rows and columns of data on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Given the structure of your HTML, you will need to do three things:

1. Create a new column
2. Total of the rows
3. Total each of the columns

```js
const
  table = document.querySelector('table'),
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length - 1,
  cols = table.querySelectorAll('tr:first-child th').length;

// Create new column
table
  .querySelector('tr:first-child')
  .append(Object.assign(document.createElement('th'),
    { innerText: 'Row Total' }));

// Total each row
table.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach((tr, index) => {
  if (index === 0) return;
  const rowTotal = [...tr.querySelectorAll('td')]
    .reduce((total, td) => total + parseInt(td.innerText, 10), 0);
  tr.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('td'),
    { innerText: rowTotal }));
});

// Total each column
const tr = document.createElement('tr');
for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
  let colTotal = 0;
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    colTotal += parseInt(table.querySelector(`tr:nth-child(${row + 2}) td:nth-child(${col + 1})`).innerText, 10);
  }
  tr.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('td'),
    { innerText: colTotal }));
}
table.append(tr);
```

```css
body { background: rgb(45, 45, 45); color: hsl(210,8%,82.5%); font-family: sans-serif; font-size: smaller; }
table, th, td { border: thin solid hsl(210, 4.5%, 30.5%); } 
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
th, td { padding: 8px; }
tr:first-child { background: hsl(0, 0%, 22.5%); color: hsl(210, 4%, 95%); }
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>Cells</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made a solution with class identifiers, but yours is really great https://codepen.io/ecupaio/pen/ExRdXmB?editors=1111

Comment: thanks for helping someone on the help people with code forum instead of scolding them.